# Issue deserializating JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON object:

```
string bodyText = " {\"id\":16751112,\"firstname\":{\"value\":\"Sydni\",\"versions\":[{\"value\":\"Sydni\",\"source-type\":\"FORM\",\"source-id\":\"0eec9e33-4e82-4511-85ef-83556395e046\",\"source-label\":\"First Name\"}  ";
```

and a class that maps to the json object:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

The following code populates the id property, but not the first name:

```
Person _Person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(bodyText);
```

Can someone please help me deserialize the fistname element in the json string object and store in in my `_Person` object?

Comment: Maybe, because `firstname` is not a string but a property in your JSON?

Comment: `firstname` in your class is a `string`, in your json the `firstname` property is an object.

Comment: I would suggest to post your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ and let it generate you the correct `Person` C# class.

Comment: @UweKeim in Visual Studio,  there is a tool, you can past json string as c# classes. _"Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes"_.

Comment: It's a least a duplicate

Comment: @SeM, don't you need a valid Json for that ?

Comment: @DragandDrop yeap. If you have a part of json code, that is invalid, just make it valid, and paste it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your posted `JSON` is incorrect - there is no closing `]` and two `}` - it should be:

```
"{\"id\":16751112,\"firstname\":{\"value\":\"Sydni\",\"versions\":[{\"value\":\"Sydni\",\"source-type\":\"FORM\",\"source-id\":\"0eec9e33-4e82-4511-85ef-83556395e046\",\"source-label\":\"First Name\"}]}}"
```

Also, `firstname` in `JSON` is not `string`, it is object.

Your classes should be:

```
public class Version
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Source-type { get; set; }
    public string Source-id { get; set; }
    public string Source-label { get; set; }
}

public class Firstname
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public IList<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Firstname Firstname { get; set; }
}
```